# How do return types for signals work in Vala?

Tags: signals-slots, return-type, vala

In Vala I can write a class like this:

```
class Foo {
    public signal int foo();
}
```

where the return type of a signal is non-void. How does this work? What will the result of the signal emission be if there is no listener or more than one listener connected to the signal? I can't seem to find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vala will just inherit [how GObject handles such a situation](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-emit):

> Note that `g_signal_emit()` [and most other emitting methods] resets the return value to the default if no handlers are connected, in contrast to `g_signal_emitv()` [which passes by an output `GValue` and just leaves it alone in that case]

You can see the Vala version of that doc [here](https://valadoc.org/gobject-2.0/GLib.Signal.emit.html). Emitting the signal with `some_foo.foo()` will just delegate to that ultimately, as testing will show:

```
class Foo
{
  public signal int foo();
}

public static int
main(string[] args)
{
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  // foo.foo.connect( () => { return 42; } );
  int result = foo.foo();
  return result;
}
```

With the line that calls `.connect()` commented out, the `result` is 0, which is the default value for a `GValue` holding an `int`.

That's for the case of zero handlers. For multiple, as [stunningpotato indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818506/how-do-return-types-for-signals-work-in-vala/49818799?noredirect=1#comment86991668_49818799), the return value will, typically, be the result of the last signal handler that gets called:

> If no accumulator function was provided, the value returned by the last handler run will be returned by `g_signal_emit`.

And, excepting object-provided handlers, you can control which the last is:

> The user-provided signal handlers are called in the order they were connected in.

As the 1st of those docs says, you can pass a custom accumulator to decide what happens with the results of multiple handlers, to handle more complex cascades.

Comment: Also it might be worth mentioning that if a signal has multiple handlers, the return value will be the one of the _last_ signal handler that has been called:

"If no accumulator function was provided, the value returned by the last handler run will be returned by g_signal_emit." (Taken from [https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/signal.html])

Comment: @stunningpotato That definitely is worth mentioning; thanks. Somehow I breezed right past the "or more than one" part of the question! I'll add that to my answer and cite you.